# how to compare between values from dropdown list in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, drop-down-menu, xlsx, index-match

Please I have question, How can I compare between 7 different values in excel? and show the lowest value?

These values a user choose them from dropdown lists.

##Example

How many hours do you sleep? "dropdown list contain (8 Hrs, 9Hrs, 10Hrs)"
How many time spend watching movie? " "dropdown list contain (8 Hrs, 9Hrs, 10Hrs)"

So, If user choose 10 Hrs for sleep and 8 Hrs for movie, How excel can return the lowest value?

Comment: `=MIN(A1:A7)`? Unless I'm misunderstanding your request.

Comment: No, I've explain what i mean in the example above.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @Norah are the numbers formatted as numbers or is the cell actually written as "8 Hrs" reading it as text? You may have to say something like `=min( value(left([1st Cell], len([1st cell])-4)), value(left([2nd Cell], len([2nd cell])-4)))` This removes the " Hrs" from the text, and looks only at the value in the beginning assuming a space between the number and Hrs. However, you can format the cells to actually store numbers and only add " Hrs" as formatting which makes this a much more straightforward task if you're interested in that approach. It would only require re-formatting the list.